# No desktop after cleaning stuff with Ubuntu tweak

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I used janitor from Ubuntu Tweak and after restarting my computer, there is nothing there. No top panel, no left launher, no dash...nothing.

Is there a way to get everything back?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and reboot. it is Just a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just don't have luck today. Now screen is not respondig (not even external), so I'll leave everything for today and check it out tommorrow. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal using "Ctrl,Alt & T" or a TTY using "Ctrl,Alt & F1" then try using the following command :

```
 unity --reset
```

See also:

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: I tried this and there is a lot of errors and warning, that compiz (core) couldn't loud plugins and in the end it is written: Compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen, you should probably file a bug about this.